# Get keyboard keyPress in windows service (vb)

Tags: vb.net, windows-services, keyboard, barcode, keypress

I am working on a windows service application that required to get the barcode reader characters and saving the value in database, I have tried some methods like this one:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C

But they not working in the windows service app, does anyone knows how can I get the keyboard/barcode reader characters in the windows service?

Appreciate the help in advance,

Regards,

Comment: Windows Services run in Session 0 starting in Vista. I don't believe you can hook mouse or keyboard events from a Windows Service due to that separation, without resorting to doing something at the driver level.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned you can't get access to the keyboard and screen from a windows service in Windows platforms starting from Vista (the interact with desktop setting is no longer supported)

So you are better off just writing a standard application that launches when a user logs into the workstation.

Since most barcode readers function like keyboards your other problem will be determining when a barcode has been entered as opposed to normal keyboard activity. Either using some kind of attention sequence (like clicking on a tray icon) or timing the speed of characters (barcode characters will appear to be "typed" very quickly)

Your global keyboard hook will work just fine from a user-mode application too :-)

Happy coding